# Error: TypeScript error in /home/runner/work/avi/avi/node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(149,100): Type expected. TS1110

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

When I build my react project I get an error like this.

```
export type ExtractRouteOptionalParam<T extends string, U = string | number | boolean> = T extends `${infer Param}?`      
  ? { [k in Param]?: U }
  : T extends `${infer Param}*`
  ? { [k in Param]?: U }
```

[image: Build log]

How to solve this?

Comment: What TypeScript version is your workflow using?

Comment: @kelly we are using 3.8.3

Comment: Well there ya go, your TypeScript version is out of date and doesn't support template literal types.

Comment: @kelly Okay, but we didn't have any issues until today. What is the reason? and this is inside node modules

Comment: I'm not sure about that but you should just upgrade your TypeScript version to fix the problem.

Comment: @kelly from which version does typescript support template literals?

Comment: Why not just use latest?

Comment: Thank you @kelly I will let you know when things are fixed.

Comment: found solutions? i still have the same problem with 4.8.3

Comment: this is frustating, broke all of a sudden....typescript upgrade gave more issues

Comment: @Hemanthvrm What are the issues?

Comment: As you mentioned in comment map undefined…I can’t upgrade react-scripts, i already ejected application

Comment: What do you mean by ejecting the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am adding an answer for future reference for others.

**Yes like others mentioned typescript was the issue.**

I upgraded it to the latest version (currently `4.8.3`). After upgrading, I had to fix a type issue on my `redux saga` file and I had to upgrade `react-scripts` to `4.0.1` to fix the `Parsing error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`.

Comment: i've upgraded typescript to 4.8.3 but i still have the same error

Comment: @JacopoMosconi do you still have the problem?

Comment: I recreated the project from scratch, now it doesn't give me any problems anymore

Comment: @JacopoMosconi great.

Answer (score 2):

I've added `@types/react-router` with a version of `5.1.14` as a dependency to my **package.json** file and installed it which solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**First option:**

As Rohan Jayraj mentioned, it is better to upgrade typescript and react-scripts.

**Second Option:**

If you have ejected your application and have no other option then follow this

Delete lock files and node_modules in your repo

- yarn.lock/ package-lock.json
- node_modules

Run below commands to install and start your app

- npm install --legacy-peer-deps
- npm build [for prod]
- npm start [for dev]

This is happening because dependency packages [react router in this case] using @types/react as a dependency with version * mentioned in their dependencies, rather than an optional peer dependency.

This issue will repeat for all the react typescript applications with new kind of types error everytime.

[error may be different everytime but this solution works]

Answer (score 0):

[image]I meet seem issue on yesterday. And I use typescript version is 3.9.3. I had try version 3.9.10 cannot sovle this problem

Comment: try to upgrade it to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

I updated typescript version to 4.1.6 and it worked for me. I tried newest version of typescript. It also works, but it doesn't support all the features I need.